# MPMoviePlayerController controls hide \ show notification?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I detected when user touch to hide or show the MPMoviePlayerController controls ?
Is there a notification or other way ?

Comment: There is unfortunately no such thing.

Comment: Maybe if you explained a bit what you where trying to achieve, we could suggest a workaround?

Comment: @Till
I have MPMoviePlayerController in full screen. the video frame is diffrent then the MPMoviePlayerController frame (depends on the video offcourse),

I want to detect when the user tap on the area outside the video but inside the MPMoviePlayerController.

For example, like in UIImageView and UIImage when you can know the size of the uiimage insdie the uiimageview. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer would be; not possible.

Reasoning: 
The `MPMoviePlayerController` is to be regarded entirely opaque and should not be modified / accessed other than the documentation supports.

From its [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Consider a movie player view to be an opaque structure. You can add
>   your own custom subviews to layer content on top of the movie but you
>   must never modify any of its existing subviews.

However, you may get away by adding you own gesture recognizer to the view hierachy exposed by that controller. Make sure that your newly introduced gestures dont interfere with the existing (`requireGestureRecognizerToFail` etc.).
But note, that is subject to break on every new iOS release as you will need to modify its existing gesture recognizers and that might be considered as a dealbreaker for submitting to iTunes. From my personal experience, that is not commonly detected by apple's review team and therefore could be an option.

The only "perfectly legal" option you have is disabling the control interface altogether (setting `MPMovieControlStyle`, to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`) and adding your own, resembling the original interface as far as you need it. Note that the complete functionality of that original interface is not entirely trivial - plan more than a day for that task. I have done loads of stuff like that and I can tell you that even after that experience, I would plan a week for fully implementing those things.